# Cypress API calls are not triggered for button event, multiple containers

Tags: javascript, containers, dom-events, cypress

Cypress not catching click event triggered hence API end points are not called for multiple containers.

It’s very difficult to explain issue, tried my best any hints are really appreciated.

I can’t share any application details.

I have a main UI application interacting with couple of backend components. API calls are made to endpoints with the same base URL but API containers are different based on component.

Manual Test steps;

1. Visit application url In main UI click search link
2. New tab/form (in same window) is opened which will interact with component 1
3. New tab is a form, fill in details and click verify button
4. 2 API calls are triggered 1 : button click event success for container 1  2: API call to container 2
5. On successful 2 API call , page returns to main application page with search result details

In cypress runner for step 4 only 1 API  call for container 1 is triggered with 200 success response.
Unfortunately second API call for container 2 was not triggered.

Asked developers about this, suggestion was cypress is not catching triggers, container 2 is not reachable from container 1.

I am stuck here, not sure what to search for or ask developers. Anyone noticed similar issue?

Comment: Add the code that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing much I can read you this quote from cypress.io

"Can I test anchor links that open in a new tab?
Cypress does not and may never have multi-tab support for various reasons.
Luckily there are lots of clear and safe workarounds that enable you to test this behavior in your application."

Maybe this could help: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links